# VirtualBox VM with a suddenly smaller screen

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I have a Windows 7 VM that I use for testing purposes. It's running on a Windows 10 host, with Guest Additions installed. For a long time it worked flawlessly, but all of a sudden the screen was smaller.

[image: how the screen looks]

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Guest Additions and it didn't work. I also tried starting on safe mode (the screen was still small) to uninstall Guest Additions and then reinstall. I upgraded from VirtualBox 6.1 to 7.0. I enabled/disabled 3d acceleration (it was disabled when it worked before). I added more processors (it was using 1 when it worked). I added more RAM (it was on 4GB when it worked). I set video memory to max values (256mb). I verified my graphics controller is set to VBoxSVGA (other options say they're invalid).

I even went back to a snapshot that I have for whenever I need to "reset" my machine, and it still didn't work.

My last attempt was to upgrade Guest Additions, but it seems to be stuck at 81%. Even if I close VirtualBox, shut down the machine, restart it, disable network, enable 3D acceleration... It seems to be stuck at 81% forever, so I can't find out if this has to do with the sudden screen size change.

[image: guest additions upgrade stuck]

I'm not sure what else to try. I have lost about 3 hours on this and don't even know why it started looking like this for no reason.

Any suggestions I haven't tried?

Comment: You upgraded VBOX version.  Try:   Uninstall Guest Extensions in the Guest machine.  Back up the Guest machine.  Uninstall VBOX completely. Restart the host machine.  Update Windows and all Drivers especially  Video. Restart again. Install VBOX.  Start the Guest and try installing newest Extensions again.